# How to use automatic late binding in C#?

Tags: c#, class, late-binding

Please take a loot at my code:

```
public class TweenerBase {
    public void Update() {}
}

public class Vector3Tweener : TweenerBase {
    public void Update() { ... }
}

public class ColorTweener : TweenerBase {
    public void Update() { ... }
}
```

In some another class I call:

```
private List < TweenerBase > tweens;

tweens = new List < TweenerBase > ();

ColorTweener tween1 = new ColorTweener();
Vector3Tweener tween2 = new Vector3Tweener();

tweens.Add( tween1 );
tweens.Add( tween2 );
```

The problem appears when I call:

```
tweens[ 0 ].Update();
```

it calls: TweenerBase.Update() not the ColorTweener.Update() as I expected. I can fix it with something like this:

```
if ( tweens[ 0 ].type == "ColorTween" ) ( (ColorTween) tweens[ 0 ] ).Update();
```

but it's very inconvenient solution if I use something like:

```
( (ColorTween) tweens[ 0 ] ).Update();
float value = ( (ColorTween) tweens[ 0 ] ).GetCurrentValue();
( (ColorTween) tweens[ 0 ] ).SomeAnotherVoid();
( (ColorTween) tweens[ 0 ] ).SomeAnotherVoid2();
```

It looks incredible :) Is there a way to make a late binding to call just:

```
tweens[ 0 ].Update();
```

and it would call ColorTweener.Update() automatically?

Comment: In Java, methods are `virtual` by default (and there's no keyword for it). If you want to achieve the same thing in C# you'll need to add `virtual` to the declaration in `TweenerBase` (as others have said).

In this case it looks like your abstract class just has an empty method. If you used an `interface` instead you'd make it so that things inheriting from `TweenerBase` would have to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use virtual on your base class method and override it on your sub-classes, currently you're implicitly using new on your sub-class methods so calling update when passing the base class around will call the base class method.

Answer (score 1):

Why have you not made Update() function virtual?

Answer (score 0):

If you want derived classes's methods  to hide base's methods, you have to use the `new` keyword in the derived class's method declaration:

```
class derived : base
{
    public new void method() { }
}
```

Alternatively, if the base class is just a container by which you get to manipulate different subclasses at once, you can declare the method as `abstract` in the base, providing its implementations by overriding in the derived ones.

```
abstract class base
{ 
    public abstract void method();
}

class derived : base
{
    public override void method()
    { // your code }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `virtual` keyword in base class, and `override` keyword in derived classes for this to work as you expect.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tweens = new List<TweenerBase>();

            var tween0 = new TweenerBase();
            var tween1 = new ColorTweener();
            var tween2 = new Vector3Tweener();

            tweens.Add(tween0);
            tweens.Add(tween1);
            tweens.Add(tween2);

            foreach (var tween in tweens)
            {
                tween.Update();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TweenerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Make sure you mark the base implementation as 'virtual'.
        /// </summary>
        public virtual void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(TweenerBase));
        }
    }

    public class Vector3Tweener : TweenerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Make sure to user 'override' keyword to override the base implementation.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(Vector3Tweener));
        }
    }

    public class ColorTweener : TweenerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Make sure to user 'override' keyword to override the base implementation.
        /// </summary>
        public override void Update()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(nameof(ColorTweener));
        }
    }
}
```

This program prints out:

```
TweenerBase
ColorTweener
Vector3Tweener
```